# Getting rid of the "Windows boot manager" when dual booting

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 20.04, uefi, windows

I've done some research but I didn't find any relevant answers.

So I have a dual booting system where I've installed ubuntu and windows. The Windows EFI boot manager is on the same EFI partition as ubuntu. Basically I've first installed Ubuntu which automatically created an EFI partition (I selected to erase whole disk option) and then installed windows and specified it to use the previously created EFI partition. From here, everything works but when I press F11 when booting up my computer, it shows me an ubuntu boot entry and a windows boot manager entry which then one that I want to delete. I've already used efibootmgr to delete that windows entry but every time I reboot my computer it just forgets what I've done with efibootmgr... But using efibootmgr to delete lets say the entry for Linux Mint, pop!_os or whatever linux distro works as expected ! It only doesn't with the windows boot manager.

What I've found it that deleting manually the Microsoft folder from the EFI partition and using efibootmgr at the same time is working but then I can't boot to windows with grub because os-prober can't find windows anymore. Can someone please help me to get rid of this windows boot manager boot entry without breaking the ability to boot into windows ?

Comment: Grub only boots working Windows. So if Windows has issues, you may be able to directly boot Windows from UEFI and get into its repair console. Also Windows updates will turn fast start up back on, then then grub will not boot it. You have to boot into Windows to turn off fast start up again. But best to also have Windows repair/recovery flash drive for emergency boot & repair.

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone please help me to get rid of this windows boot manager boot entry without breaking the ability to boot into windows ?

Windows Boot Manager is required to boot Windows.

There is no way around this.

Comment: Just to be sure, I cannot just have the ability to boot into grub and have the option to boot in windows without deleting the windows boot manager ? I'm asking this because as I said, I was able to tho delete the entry boot for other distros with efibootmgr and thought I could do the same for windows... Thanks a lot!